# How to show lots of controlls on single UIView on iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiview, uiscrollview

I have a registration page with fields for entering personal user info and it fits the UIView, however i have also address and bank account details fields wich fit another UIView.

I want to combine these viewes and put all controlls in one single view. Is it ok to create one big view and scroll through its children.

I tryed to use UIScrollView, but i can't scroll and see all the controlls.

Btw, another design recommendations are wellcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

probably you are not using scroll view correctly,

use this in viewDidLoad where you having scrollView (IBOutlet)

```
self.scroller.scrollEnabled = YES;
    [self.scroller setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 650)];//according to you.
```

You need to make view like this [image]

size of scroll view 320 * 480.

Comment: All right! Thanks. That's exactly what i missed. Looked to change content size in Interface Builder.

Comment: I did exactly what you proposed in a different way: i set up frame size of my scrollView in interface builder(so i can see visual alignment and size of the view) to a needed size and than, in viewDidLoad, i added: [self.scrollView setContentSize:self.view.frame.size];

Answer (score 3):

Add uiscrollview in your xib file(interface builder), map that scrollview in header file,

you can directly add component in scrollview like this,

```
    [srollView addSubview:alertMessage];
    [srollView addSubview:myImage];
    [srollView addSubview:sampleButton];
    [srollView addSubview:bdayLabel];
    [srollView addSubview:bdayTF];
    [srollView addSubview:genderLabel];
    [srollView addSubview:genderTF];
    [srollView addSubview:zipLabel];
    [srollView addSubview:zipTF];
    [srollView addSubview:emailLabel];
    [srollView addSubview:emailTF];
```

set content side bigger as per your requirement

```
[srollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320, 580)];
```

Comment: It's worth emphasizing: a UIScrollView will *not* scroll unless its contentSize property is set larger than its frame!

Answer (score -1):

You need to download Apple's "Scrolling" sample code. This will show you how to use a UIScrollView

Comment: Kinda defies the point of your providing an answer then doesn't it